# Delete database file from assets folder

Tags: java, android, database, file-io, android-assets

I want to delete a file in assets folder in run-time. I have a database file in assets folder that copies to data folder at run-time but after installing my app the size of app become twice as large (assets + data folder)!

How I can delete database file from assets folder to avoid this?

Comment: AFAIK, asset folder can't be modified at runtime.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't delete a file at runtime that was delivered with your App.

See this discussion about it:

[How to remove a file in assets at run time?](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg16172.html)

The whole content of your APK is read only and can not be modified

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the above answer, one thing you can do is preferExternalStorage in manifest..which will help